# Translation of “Glasshole”

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique, argot, jeux-de-mots

[*Glasshole*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Glasshole) designates a person who constantly talks to their Google Glass, ignoring the outside world. How would you say glasshole in French?

Comment: La presse spécialisée française reprend le terme glasshole mais pourquoi ne pas lancer des idées sur fr.se avant qu'on se voit imposer dans 10 ans un mot par la commission générale de terminologie et de néologie ?

Answer (score 8):

J'utiliserais personnellement « Schtroumpf à lunettes » pour ne pas être vulgaire, mais c'est un choix personnel. Voilà quelques propositions plus insultantes :

- « Engooglé » traduit bien le coté vulgaire (pour "Enculé") mais ne parle pas de lunettes en particulier. Et n'est pas forcément évident à comprendre.
- « Glassocial » pour insister sur le fait d'être coupé du monde.
- « Glasservi », « Glassisté » ? « Assisté » a tendance à devenir une insulte mais le coté péjoratif n'est pas clair.
- « Binoclard » est une insulte générale à quelqu'un qui porte des lunettes (Google ou pas).

Answer (score 4):

Quelques propositions un peu bancales :

> - Trouduglass
> - Glasscon
> - Enfoiglass
> - Englassé

Rien de bien follichon, en tout cas très loin du jeu de mots *Glasshole* que je trouve très bon.

Comment: +1 pour trouduglass (qui garde la saveur de l'anglais en plus). J'éviterai Glasscon pour éviter le rapprochement avec Gascon, à une lettre prêt, à l'oral ! Enfoiglass est pas mal non non plus.

Answer (score 2):

An important (English-language) science fiction novel called [Snow Crash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_Crash#Metaverse) used the term "gargoyle":

> Stephenson also describes a sub-culture of people choosing to remain continuously connected to the Metaverse [i.e. the internet] by wearing portable terminals, goggles and other equipment; they are given the sobriquet "gargoyles" due to their grotesque appearance.

The "grotesque appearance" was from wearing portable computer technology and goggles, that novel being written in 1992.

So I could suggest **« Gargouille »** if they look (or behave) inhuman or other-worldly.

I don't know whether people actually see gargoyles as [benign](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gargouille#Symbole_mythique_des_gargouilles).

---

Alternatively, a **« Lunettique »** (hoping to combine Lunatique with Lunettes).

Answer (score 1):

Je propose de reprendre l'expression:

> Moucheur de cyclope

pour préserver les aspects oculaire et vulgaire de l'original anglais, tout en y ajoutant une connotation solitaire que peut évoquer quelqu'un qui ne se soucie pas des autres.

Answer (score 0):

> Un *têtard gogole 2.0*

Normalement ce devrait être *têtard à lunette gogole*, mais les lunettes sont génétiquement livrées avec une tête gogolienne 2.0, autosatisfaction hébétée incluse.

Answer (score -1):

This word is very new, so there is no translation available yet.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Seriously? This is my answer. It's ok to not like an answer.